# Global session variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm storing user language in session, and then I'm loading the language file like this:

```
$language = $this->session->userdata('language');
$this->lang->load('form_validation', $language);
```

But its pretty annoying, when I have to load the above `$language` variable in every controller, it would be better if it would be a global variable, so I could use just:

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', $language);
```

- Where `$language` var would be a global variable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really wanting a one-liner then why not just do

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', $this->session->userdata('language'));
```

As for globals in general it's usually not a good practice to create them unnecessarily.  The reason being that globals by nature can be accessed from anywhere so it's possible to update them from anywhere which can lead to hard to find bugs

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way (or at the least better than using globals) would be to define a helper function somewhere in your code (I don't know where that would be in CodeIgniter) that would load the language file for you.

But, is that really a problem?

Comment: Well, I didnt say thats a big problem, but its pretty annoying if I have to load something that could be defined globally. Isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You could place a helper within the autoload.php file ;). Located at /application/config/autoload.php

Thus defining the variable in a helper, and place the helper in the autoload['helper'] array.